# Jquery: get div class value from one page in another Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two MVC Views with some divs in one application and want to pass the Value of one div to another.

```
View1
<div id="emp-@item.Id" class="custom1">
```

View2

```html
  <div  class="bg-info" id="Search">
  <span=id="NameId">Employee Numbers</span>
 </div>
```

I want to pass the value of View2 div to View1 by the class name.

```
$('.custom1').each(function()
{         
                   var newEmp=$("#Search).appendTo($(this)).find('span:NameId').text();           
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to store value of View1.

Example

View1

```
<div id="emp-@item.Id" class="custom1">
<script>
    sessionStorage.setItem('custom1', 'your value');
</script>
```

View 2

```
<div  class="bg-info" id="Search">
  <span=id="NameId">Employee Numbers</span>
 </div>
<script>
   let custom1 = sessionStorage.getItem('custom1');
   // and use variable here
</script>
```